# Insert same ID connected to multiple selection options ID

Tags: php, html

I need to have the array pulling multiple FacultyIDs also connect to the same PubID in the FACULTYPUBLICATION table.

- FacultyName is a multiple select option field
- Publication is a single insert and creates an auto generated id
- the Publication ID gets inserted into the PUBLICATION table
- the FacultyID comes from a lookup table that is predefined
- the PubID and the FacultyID gets inserted into the FACULTYPUBLICATIONS table
- **PROBLEM:** When multiple Faculty are selected only 1 faculty gets inserted into FACULTYPUBLICATIONS. I need to find a way to connect a single PubID to multiple faculty in the FACULTYPUBLICATIONS table

  ```
      //insert form values into database                                                                                                                                                   
  $sql = "SELECT JournalName, JournalID, Rating, JournalActive from JOURNAL where JournalActive = 1;";      
  //Can take out JournalActive if we do not want it                                                                                                                        
  $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);                                                                                                                                                 
  if (!$result) {                                                                                                                                                                      
      $message  = 'Invalid query: ' . mysql_error() . "\n";                                                                                                                            
      $message .= 'Whole query: ' . $query;                                                                                                                                            
      die($message);                                                                                                                                                                   
      echo "there was an issue";                                                                                                                                                       
  } 

  $sql2 = "SELECT FName, LName, FacultyID from FACULTY where FacultyActive = 1;"; 
  //Can take out JournalActive if we do not want it                                                                                                                        
  $result2 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql2);                                                                                                                                                 
  if (!$result2) {                                                                                                                                                                      
      $message  = 'Invalid query: ' . mysql_error() . "\n";                                                                                                                            
      $message .= 'Whole query: ' . $query;                                                                                                                                            
      die($message);                                                                                                                                                                   
      echo "there was an issue";                                                                                                                                                       
  } 

      //array to hold all of the data                                                                                                                                                      
  $journals = array();                                                                                                                                                                  
      //print out all of the first names in the database   
  $rownumber = 0;                                                                                                                                 
  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {                                                                                                                                         
      $journals[$rownumber][0] = $row['JournalName'];
      $journals[$rownumber][1] = $row['JournalID'];
      $journals[$rownumber][2] = $row['JournalRating'];
      $journals[$rownumber][3] = $row['JournalActive'];
      $rownumber++;                                                                                                                                                       
  }

  $faculty = array();                                                                                                                                                                  
      //print out all of the first names in the database   
  $rownum = 0;                                                                                                                                 
  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2)) {                                                                                                                                         
      $faculty[$rownum][0] = $row['FName'];
      $faculty[$rownum][1] = $row['LName'];
      $faculty[$rownum][2] = $row['FacultyID'];
      $rownum++;                                                                                                                                                       
  }

  ?>

  <!DOCTYPE html>

  <head>
  <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <h1> Miami University </h1>
  <h4> Information Systems and Analytics Department </h4>


  </head>
  <body>

  <div class="StyleDiv" > 
  <!-- coding for journal -->
  <form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="RR2.php">


  <label for="FacultyName">Faculty Name</label>
  <select multiple="multiple" name="FacultyID" id="FacultyID">
  <?php
      for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($faculty); $i++) {
      print "<option value=\"" . $faculty[$i][2] . "\">" . $faculty[$i][0] .' '. $faculty[$i][1] . "</option>\r\n";
      }
  ?>
  </select>


  <br class="clear" />

  <br class="clear" /> 
  <label for="JournalID">Journal Name</label>
  <select name="JournalID" id="JournalID">
  <?php
      for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($journals); $i++) {
      print "<option value=\"" . $journals[$i][1] . "\">" . $journals[$i][0] . "</option>\r\n";
      }
  ?>
  </select>

  <br class="clear" />

  <label for="JournalRating">Journal Rating</label><input type="text" name="JournalRating" id="JournalRating" />
  <br class="clear" /> 


  <!-- coding for publication --> 
  <label for="Title">Publication Title</label><input type="text" name="PubID" id="PubID" />
  <br class="clear" /> 
  <label for="Year">Year</label><input type="text" name="Year" id="Year" />
  <br class="clear" /> 
  <label for="Volume">Volume</label><input type="text" name="Volume" id="Volume" />
  <br class="clear" /> 
  <label for="Issue">Issue</label><input type="text" name="Issue" id="Issue" />
  <br class="clear" /> 
  <label for="Comments">Comments</label><textarea name="Comments" id="Comments" cols="45" rows="5"></textarea>
  <br class="clear" /> 



  <input type="submit" name="Submit" id="Submit" value="Submit" />
  <br class="clear" /> 
  </br>
  </br>

  </div>
  </form>

  <?php

  //Post Parameters 
  $JournalID = $_POST['JournalID'];
  //for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($journals); $i++) {
      //if ($JournalID = $journals[$i][1]) {
      //$JournalName = $journals[$i][0];
      //}
      //}
  $Year = $_POST['Year'];  
  $Comments = $_POST['Comments'];  
  $Volume = $_POST['Volume'];  
  $Issue = $_POST['Issue'];  
  $Title = $_POST['Title'];
  $JournalRating = $_POST['JournalRating'];
  $FacultyMemID = $_POST['FacultyID'];


  //Query 



   //INSERT 
   $stmt = $conn->prepare(" INSERT INTO PUBLICATION ( JournalID, Year, Comments, Volume, Issue, Title, JournalRating )  VALUES ( '$JournalID', '$Year', '$Comments', '$Volume', '$Issue', '$Title', '$JournalRating' )"); 
   $stmt->execute(); 

  // would need to add inserts for JournalName if we re-add it in 


   $stmt = $conn->prepare(" INSERT INTO FACULTYPUBLICATIONS ( FacultyID, PubID )  VALUES ( '$FacultyMemID', last_insert_id() )"); 
   $stmt->execute();


  mysqli_close($conn);
  ?>



  </body>
  </html>
  ```

Comment: You can't mix `mysql_XX` and `mysqli_XX` functions. If you're using `mysqli_query` you have to use `mysqli_error`.

Comment: That's why I posted it as a comment, not an answer.

Comment: Another unrelated error: `<label for="FacultyName">` should be `<lable for="FacultyID">`

Comment: Could you look at another PHP code? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29595809/populate-a-text-box-based-on-a-dynamic-drop-down-box-in-php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get multiple selections, add `[]` to the name of the input:

```
<select multiple="multiple" name="FacultyID[]" id="FacultyID">
```

This tells PHP to make `$_POST['FacultyID']` an array of all the values. Then you can loop through them:

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare(" INSERT INTO PUBLICATION ( JournalID, Year, Comments, Volume, Issue, Title, JournalRating )  VALUES ( ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ? )"); 
$stmt->bind_param('sssssss', $JournalID, $Year, $Comments, $Volume, $Issue, $Title, $JournalRating);
$stmt->execute(); 

$pubID = $conn->insert_id;

$stmt = $conn->prepare(" INSERT INTO FACULTYPUBLICATIONS ( FacultyID, PubID )  VALUES ( ?, ? )"); 
$stmt->bind_param('si', $FacultyMemID, $pubID);
for ($_POST['FacultyID'] as $FacultyMemID) {
    $stmt->execute();
}
```

Note that you can't use the SQL `LAST_INSERT_ID()` in the loop, because after the first iteration it will contain the ID of the row that was just inserted into `FACULTYPUBLICATIONS`, not the ID of the row that was inserted into `PUBLICATION` before the loop. So I used the PHP `$stmt->insert_id` to get the ID.

I've also recoded using `bind_param` to prevent SQL injection.

Comment: Hm okay so this should work but for some reason it makes all of my coding stop showing up - I checked spelling and all of that is still the same. Do I need to change my arrays at all ?

Comment: I don't have access to the error log at the moment. If I get access to it then I will let you know. But it just makes a white screen show up. JournalRating in the insert statement - that has the ID JournalRating but in the database is just Rating - which should it be in the insert?

Comment: I did figure out - through commenting out things that the insert into FACULTYPUBLICATIONS is where it goes blank.

Comment: Put `error_reporting(E_ALL);` at the beginning of the script, so that errors are reported there instead of just the log.

Comment: Try using `$conn->insert_id` instead of `$stmt->insert_id`. They both exist, but the latter isn't really documented, so I think it's not intended to be used.

Comment: I just noticed that I had the arguments in the wrong order in the second `bind_param` call. But that shouldn't cause the script to go blank.

Comment: Thank you somuch for all of your help! Figured it out

Answer (score 0):

This makes it work as well because calling the array from the original function.

```
 $stmt = $conn->prepare(" INSERT INTO FACULTYPUBLICATIONS ( FacultyID, PubID )  VALUES ( ?, ? )"); 
    $stmt->bind_param('ii', $facmemid, $pubID);
     //for ($_POST['FacultyID'] as $FacultyMemID) {
     for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($FacultyMemID); $i++) {
        $facmemid = $FacultyMemID[$i]; 
        $stmt->execute();
        }
```

Comment: There's no difference between using this `for` loop and the `foreach` loop that I wrote, other than your choice of a different variable name.